# Given $a,b,c$ are the sides of a triangle. Prove that $\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}<2$

Tags: inequality, triangles, geometric-inequalities

Given $a,b,c$ are the sides of a triangle. Prove that $\dfrac{a}{b+c}+\dfrac{b}{c+a}+\dfrac{c}{a+b}<2$.

My attempt:
I could solve it by using the semiperimeter concept. I tried to transform this equation since it is a homogeneous equation as $f(a,b,c)=f(ta,tb,tc)$. I considered $a+b+c=1$ and thus the inequality reduces to

$$\dfrac{a}{1-a}+\dfrac{b}{1-b}+\dfrac{c}{1-c}<2$$.

This is getting quite difficult to prove, as I don't have any clue to approach. I want to solve this only by homogeneous equation transformation, so any other transformation is welcome, but not any other idea(I don't mean to be rude but that's my necessity). Please help. Thank you.

Comment: The algebraic constraints on $a, b, c$ are that they must satisfy the triangle inequality: $a < b + c$, $b < a + c$, $c < a + b$. So if you can manipulate it into a form such as Graubner's below, you're done.

Comment: That is the way I've done it, but I am trying homogeneous equations here.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Do you know there is such a proof? Could you give an example of another such result using this method?

Comment: @SimonS please visit the link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033333/show-that-for-real-a-b-c-a2b2c2abbcca/1033334#1033334

Comment: Ok, read the link. What you seem to suggest here though is that you can substitute the triangle inequality conditions with the homogeneous condition. I.e., you want a solution that doesn't use the inequalities but instead the homogeneity. My question is: are you confident there is such a solution? It's not obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As these are sides of a triangle, let  $a=x+y, b= y+z, c=z+x$, and using homogeneity, set $x+y+z=1$. The inequality is then to show:
$$\frac{1-x}{1+x}+\frac{1-y}{1+y}+\frac{1-z}{1+z} < 2$$

Note that $x \in (0, 1) \implies 1+x > 1 \implies \dfrac{1-x}{1+x}< 1-x$.  Sum that across $x, y, z$ to get the above inequality.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wanted to get the solution this way so eagerly.

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively, without much multiplying: by triangle inequality you get $\frac{a}{b+c} < 1$ and hence
$$
\frac{a}{b+c} < \frac{a + a}{a + b + c} = \frac{2a}{a + b + c}
$$
Adding 3 similar inequalities (with respectively $a, b, c$ in the numerators on the left hand side fractions) will prove the thesis.

Answer (score 1):

it is equivalent to
$a^2(b+c-a)+b^2(a+c-b)+c^2(a+b-c)+abc>0$