# Show that for real $a,b,c$, $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca$

Tags: inequality

Show that for real $a,b,c$, $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca$

We can do this in two obviously trivial ways, that is AM-GM inequality, and its equivalent system, the whole square method. Another way could be the homogeneous equation system, which is shown in the solution part.

Comment: why not $\geq$?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

For real $a,b,c;$ $$\sum(a-b)^2\ge0$$

The equality occurs if $a=b=c$

Answer (score 2):

> $$a^2+b^2+c^2-(ab+bc+ca)=\frac12[(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2]$$

Comment: Why is this down-voted?

Comment: @hengxin most probably swadhin did it

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(a,b,c)=a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca$. Then we have, $f(ta,t,b,tc)=t^2f(a,b,c)$. Hence, $f$ is homogeneous of degree two. For, $t\ne 0$, we have $f(a,b,c)>0 \iff f(ta,tb,tc)>0$. Therefore, we may make various *normalizations*. For example, we may set, $a=1,b=1+x,c=1+y$ and get $x^2+y^2-xy=(x-\frac{y}{2})^2+\dfrac{3y^2}{4}>0$.

This is a solution using homogeneous equations.

Answer (score 1):

**Using caushy-Schwartz Inequality::**

$$\displaystyle (a^2+b^2+c^2)\cdot (b^2+c^2+a^2)\geq (ab+bc+ca)^2$$ and equality hold when $\displaystyle \frac{a}{b}=\frac{b}{c}=\frac{c}{a}.$