# Prove that $\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{c+a}\ge\frac{3}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, summation, fractions

For $a\geq b\geq c >0$. Prove that $$\dfrac{a}{a+b}+\dfrac{b}{b+c}+\dfrac{c}{c+a}\ge\dfrac{3}{2}$$

$a=100;b=1;c=1/100$ it's wrong ???

---

$\dfrac{a}{a+b}+\dfrac{b}{b+c}+\dfrac{c}{c+a}\ge\dfrac{3}{2}$

$<=>\sum\frac{a}{a+b}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{b}{b+c}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{c}{c+a}-\frac{1}{2}\geq 0$

$<=>\sum \frac{a-b}{2(a+b)}\geq 0$$<=>\sum\frac{z-y}{2x}\geq 0$

$<=>xy^2+yz^2+xz^2-x^2y-y^2z-z^2x\geq 0$

$<=>(y-x)(z-y)(z-x)\geq 0$

And we have $y-x\le 0; z-x\le 0; z-y\geq 0$

we are done !?

Comment: It's not clear what you are saying in the last line. Do you think those values of $a,b,c$ yield a counter-example?

Comment: If $a=100,b=1,c=1/100$ then $\frac{a}{a+b}=\frac{100}{101},\frac{b}{b+c}=\frac{100}{101}$ and thus the inequality holds without the third term.

Comment: Different but related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032309/given-a-b-c-are-the-sides-of-a-triangle-prove-that-dfracabc-dfracb?rq=1

Comment: hey you ! b+c other a+b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a\geq b\geq c>0$ we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b}-\frac{3}{2}=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a}{a+b}-\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a-b}{2(a+b)}=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)(c^2+ab+ac+bc)}{2\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b)}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{c^2a-c^2b}{2\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b)}=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2b-a^2c}{2\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b)}=\frac{(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)}{2\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b)}\geq0$$

Comment: $∏$ ? $∏(a+b)=(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$ ?

Comment: @Word Shallow Yes! $\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b)=(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$.